# How to prove that a particular (sub-)category has a projective generator.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is an abelian $k$-linear category ($k$ a field) in which every object is of finite length and every $k$-vector space $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ is finite dimensional.

How does one prove the fact that for every object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the full subcategory $X^*$ of $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects are subquotients of the $X^n$ has a projective generator?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? I only remember a discussion in Milne's "Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes", where he proves the case where ${\mathcal C}=\langle X\rangle$  (wlog) is moreover equipped with an exact, faithful functor to $k\text{-Vect}$: he then shows that this functor is automatically representable, and the representing object is then a projective generator of $\mathcal C$.